# How to insert a video into a text with HTML?

Tags: html

I tried looking everywhere but have no luck so far on how to add a video link into text.

I'm trying to insert a video into the word "Example" so that whenever a person were to click on that word, the video will pop up on the same window. I'm imagining that it should work like
`<a class="image-with-lightbox" href="/a/sample_picture.png"> <img src="/a/sample_picture.png" width="0">Example</a>`

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your level of familiarity or experience with HTML in general? Where is the video located (YouTube? Self-hosted?). Where will this HTML be displayed?

Comment: beginner. I'm trying to add a video that is being hosted by Wistia. Basically, it's an article that I'm working on on Zendesk. I'm trying to embed (not sure if I use the word correctly) a video link to a word.

Comment: Does this help? https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004321248-Expanding-images-in-Help-Center-articles - just change the `<img />` to a `<video>` or `<iframe>` depending on how the Wistia works.

Answer (score 0):

An example i get from w3schools with this two links:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

```js
window.onload = function init() {
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  // Get the link that opens the modal
  var link = document.getElementById("myLink");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  link.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#" id="myLink">Open Modal</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="video_url_here.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video_url_here.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
    </video>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```